Adding text inputs and image upload inputs from a simple HTML form to Google Sheets using Apps Scripts?
I am using a simple HTML form to collect inputs from users and I want to add each submission in its own row in Google Sheets. So far, I am able to add the text inputs to Google Sheets successfully, but when I added logic to add images, I get an error that is very difficult to decipher.
Here is the HTML File:
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
    </head>
    <body id="body">  
        <form id="form" method="POST" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/exec">
          <div class="form-control">
            <label for="name" id="label-name" class="name">
                Name:
            </label>
            <!-- Input Type Text -->
            <input type="text" id="name" name="Name" placeholder="Enter name here." />
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <label for="role" id="label-role">
                Role:
            </label>
            <!-- Dropdown options -->
            <select name="Role" id="role">
                <option value="select">--Select--</option>
                <option value="associate">Associate</option>
                <option value="partner">Partner</option>
                <option value="volunteer">Volunteer</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <label for="neighborhood" id="label-neighborhood">
                Neighborhood:
            </label>
            <!-- Dropdown options -->
            <select name="Neighborhood" id="neighborhood">
                <option value="select">--Select--</option>
                <option value="manhattan">Manhattan</option>
                <option value="brooklyn">Brooklyn</option>
                <option value="queens">Queens</option>
                <option value="bronx">Bronx</option>
                <option value="statenisland">Staten Island</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <label for="photo1" id="label-photo1">
                Photo 1. Profile picture
            </label>
            <!-- Input Type File -->
            <input type="file" id="photo1" name="Photo1">
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <label for="photo1" id="label-photo1">
                Photo 2. First hobby picture
            </label>
            <!-- Input Type File -->
            <input type="file" id="photo2" name="Photo2">
          </div>
          <div class="form-control">
            <label for="photo1" id="label-photo1">
                Photo 2. Second hobby picture
            </label>
            <!-- Input Type File -->
            <input type="file" id="photo3" name="Photo3">
          </div>
          <div class="submitbutton">
            <button type="submit">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

When I followed this guide, it worked perfectly: https://github.com/levinunnink/html-form-to-google-sheet
Original Code.gs that works fine:
const sheetName = 'Sheet1'
const scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function initialSetup () {
  const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    const nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    const newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Date' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}

However I updated the Code.gs to add logic to include the 3 images and now it won't work. The error message is: "error" : { "name" : "Exception" }
Here is the updated Code.gs file that does not work:
const sheetName = 'Sheet1'
const scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function initialSetup () {
  const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    const nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    const newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      if(header === 'Photo1'){
        var contentType = 'image/jpeg';
        var image = e.parameter[header];
        var image = image.getAs(contentType);
        
        var file = DriveApp.createFile(image);
        file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
        sheet.getRange(NextRow, 4, 1, 1).setFormula("=IMAGE(\"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + file.getId() + "\")");
      } else if(header === 'Photo2') {
        var contentType = 'image/jpeg';
        var image = e.parameter[header];
        var image = image.getAs(contentType);
        
        var file = DriveApp.createFile(image);
        file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
        sheet.getRange(NextRow, 5, 1, 1).setFormula("=IMAGE(\"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + file.getId() + "\")");
        
      } else if(header === 'Photo3') {
        var contentType = 'image/jpeg';
        var image = e.parameter[header];
        var image = image.getAs(contentType);
        
        var file = DriveApp.createFile(image);
        file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
        sheet.getRange(NextRow, 6, 1, 1).setFormula("=IMAGE(\"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + file.getId() + "\")");
        
      } else {
        return header === 'Date' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
      } 
      
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'message' : 'Thank you for your submission!'}))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'message' : 'There was an error in your submission. Please contact xxx@gmail.com.', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}

The other questions/answers I found involve single images without other form inputs like text data.
